# Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "Учись (,) играя" ?

Tags: пунктуация

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему.

Answer (score 8):

А что вы хотите сказать? Если учись в процессе игры, учись и играй, тогда играя - деепричастие, выделяется запятой. Если вы хотите сказать учись легко, играючи, тогда деепричастие приобретает наречное значение образа действия и  запятая не нужна.